# min-width and max-width with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

How to emulate for ie6?

Comment: Please invest more effort in explaining what it is you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to emulate max-width:

```
var maxWidth = 300;    
if ( $('SELECTOR').width() > maxWidth ) $('SELECTOR').width(maxWidth);
```

the same can be applied for width, height, min and max with minor adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to codeburger's anwser that you might as well put this in an external JS file or JS block that's shown only to IE6 via conditional comments.

Comment: if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
  if(parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) == 6) { etc